# Poly space has error Pointer is outside its bounds

Tags: c

for poly space why it is illegally deference pointer? pointing to line 8 
the error is pointer is outside its bounds.

```
void Init(void) {

    T_u32 *topPtr  = GetStackPtr();
    T_u32 *basePtr = BASE_ADRESS;

    do {
        /* Initializing the stack */
        *(--topPtr) = (T_u32)INIT_VALUE;
    } while (topPtr > basePtr);

}
```

I have done testing this but it seems like 
I need to fix the pointer is outside its bounds.